# vim randomly breaks syntax highlighting

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

When working on a remote server with rather large ping times, the syntax highlighting suddenly and seeming randomly breaks. When that happens, it looks like this:

[image]

The syntax highlighting is fine til line 24, after that everything is grey. I can fix it by randomly scrolling around or close open vim. But I can neither reproduce the problem, nor reproduce the fix.

This does not happen when I work with exactly the same version of vim and exactly the same .vimrc. Therefore I suspect there's something wrong on the server. Especially I suspect the problem might arise due to the long ping times (~ 170 ms).

Did anyone see a similar behaviour?

Comment: Does pressing `<C-l>` fix it when it happens?

Comment: I get the same behaviour with local files, if they are large.

Comment: what version of vim are you using?

Comment: @xxor I'm using vim 7.4 including patches: 1-516.

Comment: `<C-l>` doesn't redraw instantly, maybe `:redraw` or `:redraw!` will work?

Comment: @texasflood Neither of them works for me.

Answer (score 55):

I have had this behaviour occasionally, but I've always just let it be, as its only affected me while editing very large files.

However, now you've brought it up I went looking for a solution. I found this page: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_syntax_highlighting, which has the following command:

```
:syntax sync fromstart
```

Running that solves it for me, although it does take a while to complete.

**Edit:** Following that page's suggestion to use `minlines` argument, I've found that I get instantaneous and usually-correct highlighting by running this command instead:

```
:syntax sync minlines=20
```

But obviously you can play with the value to trade-off speed and accuracy to your own taste.

Comment: Neither of these commands fix it for me. It seems I have a different issue?

Comment: I have had similar issues on local vim several times, all with relatively large files. I used to scroll up/down a few times, sometimes fold/unfold all folds to get it corrected. And the `syntax sync minlines=20` seems to be working for me.

Comment: I often encounter broken syntax highlighting with text files as small as ~15KB, therefore I assigned a function key to fixing it: `map <F12> :syntax sync fromstart<cr>`. The `minlines` parameter does not correct highlighting in my case.

Comment: You could try this `:set redrawtime=10000` . It will take some time, but I found that it doesn't break formatting. 

You can find more about this issue here: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2790

Answer (score 17):

I have the similar issue when paging up/down.

Fixed by this config.

```
autocmd BufEnter * syntax sync fromstart
```

Ref: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_syntax_highlighting

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is a solution, I have not been able to find other occurences of this case. I remember seeing something like this once, but I don´t know how to replicate. I suspect that it isn´t the connection though, but something in vim. I miss the beginning of the file to be able to replicate properly.

But you can try different options, like:

```
:syntax sync ccomment
```

this is if the beginning of the file is in a c-comment or something; I am not sure if or how this applies to your case; either way, check the docs if there is something useful for you:
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syn-sync