# Syntax highlighting get lost

Tags: vim, syntax, markdown, syntax-highlighting, color-scheme

Sometimes when I open a markdown file, there is no syntax highlight if I do not open from the beginning of the file (when I quit last time leaving the cursor in the middle of the file). I have to jump to previous lines where the syntax highlights exists and run the cursor down such that the lines my cursor passes will recover their syntax highlights.

How could I fix this problem, or is there any command for me to refresh the syntax highlight so that I could run it when I open the file/buffers ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vim randomly breaks syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235102/vim-randomly-breaks-syntax-highlighting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/markdown.vim` (in the version from *2016 Aug 29* that I have) uses `:syn sync minlines=10`. You can read about the possible sync approaches at [`:help :syn-sync`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-sync). The sledgehammer method would be `:syntax sync fromstart` (put e.g. in `~/.vim/after/syntax/markdown.vim`) to force syncing from the start. You can try that out, or tweak the original `minlines=` value. What works depends on the complexity of your markdown files.

Comment: Thanks your advice, I add a line ```syntax sync fromstart``` to my ```~/.vimrc```, but find it does not work. I still have syntax highlight missing when opening some markdown file. what is the correct way to configure my vimrc please ?

Comment: `.vimrc` is sourced at the beginning; the markdown syntax overrides that later. As I mentioned, this is a use case for the _after_ directory hierarchy.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark. This way, the question is marked as closed, and you increase your chances of getting answers to future questions, as this shows that you care about the answers.